# Adding grand totals to chart birt

Tags: charts, birt

I have a BIRT crosstab report with a grand total column. I created a chart based on that report. But in the chart wizard, the grand total column is not available to add as either an axes or an optional grouping. In fact, it doesn't display at all.

I want a pie chart that uses the grand total. I even thought that maybe I could sum the data in the wizard with a BIRT function, that didn't work either.

Here's the scenario: I have an aggregated data element, E, that contains multiple values.
So, for example, count(E1) = 10, E2 = 32, etc.

***I want a grand total of all the elements so that I can create a pie chart that displays each data element count as part of the total count.***

I don't see a mechanism to accomplish this. I'm new to BIRT so it's very possible that I'm overlooking something basic. Any help is appreciated. Please ask if you need more information.

Regards,
Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created the chart from the crosstab (right-click the crosstab->create chart view), then all databindings are made available in the chart, including the grand total.

However generally these bindings don't have a very explicit name, it is tricky to recognize them when designing expressions in the chart.

In the crosstab view if we double-click the grand total, its data-binding name is displayed (greyed out) at the top of the dialog. Use this in your chart expressions.